# How to upload byte[] to Minio

Tags: c#, .net, upload, minio, file-storage

```
public async Task Put(byte[] data)
{
    var args = new PutObjectArgs { };
    args.WithBucket("buckethead");
    args.WithObject(Guid.NewGuid.ToString());
    args.WithRequestBody(data);
    args.WithContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    await _client.PutObjectAsync(args);
}
```

First of all I gotta say that Minio is very poorly documented.

Second - how do I send byte[]? Example above gives the following error:

```
One of FileName or ObjectStreamData must be set.
```

But FileName implies usage of physically stored file and ObjectStreamData  - there is no such method in PutObjectArgs !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods are fluent (though you don't *need* to use that), you're looking for [`WithStreamData()`](https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet/blob/9a9d202219095b33173d931b4358556f24d771aa/Minio/DataModel/ObjectOperationsArgs.cs#L1886), and wrap your byte array in a MemoryStream:

```
new PutObjectArgs()
    .With...
    .WithStreamData(new MemoryStream(data))
    .With...
```

The `WithRequestBody()` you call now will serialize the passed object to XML.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Could you by chance tell me why it gives me ```"There is an error in XML document (0, 0)."``` exception now? 'data' is an .xlsx workbook as byte[] created using ClosedXML. Did I specify content type wrong?

Comment: Without a stack trace or context, no, I can't say anything about that. Seems like something tries to parse something as XML, which it isn't.

Comment: this exception is raised by MinioClient when ```await _client.PutObjectAsync(args);``` is called. Am I only supposed to store XML in Minio and other file types are not supported?

Comment: That's a different question though. Perhaps update your question with the exact code and exception you have, or ask a new one.